# jquery sparkline giving undefined only in IE7

Tags: jquery, sparklines

The array values give undefined result only in IE7 and above...I have no idea what I am doing here!

Html:

Sparkline appears here:

```
javascript :-
// jsfiddle configured to load jQuery Sparkline 2.1
// http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

// Values to render
var values = [99.51,0.00,0.49];

// Draw a sparkline for the #sparkline element
$('#sparkline').sparkline(values, {
type: 'pie', 
borderWidth: 0,
height: '1.40em',
disableTooltips: true,
sliceColors: ['#088A08','#2E64FE','#FF8000'],
offset: 180
});
```

Result:
Sparkline appears here: undefined

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ankit1912/pQhCY/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug with the plugin (fixed in the development tree).  More details in the bug the questioner opened:  https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/issues/49